# Slow Internet Speed = Slow Data Collected?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

today I have a question about HTML data collecting in C#. Let's say I have a Listbox and I want to borrow data from the web instead of inserting a text file in ListBox.

**Q: What If ,my internet connection is slow?
 Will it affect the data as well? Will it load the data slow or fast in my ListBox?**

```
List<string> DictionaryList = new List<string>();
//WEB 
WebClient web = new WebClient();
String html = web.DownloadString("http://www.example.org/");
MatchCollection m1 = Regex.Matches(html, @"<li>\s*(.+?)\s*</li>", RegexOptions.Singleline);
foreach (Match m in m1)
{
    string city = m.Groups[1].Value;
    DictionaryList.Add(city);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: If it's *too* slow, it might time out. You would need to handle a WebException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `String html = web.DownloadString("http://www.example.org/");` will download according to your Internet speed. If your Internet is slow, then it will execute in a few seconds instead of, say, half a second.

But downloading just a single page only downloads the actual HTML file itself (not the images, scripts, styles, videos etc) so even on a slow connection, it should take no more than about two seconds for typical websites.

After that line, you have nothing to do with Internet speed as you've got the whole page in your computer's memory, so regex matching will execute practically instantly without using the Internet.